# Does being denied entry to a country affect future travel to other countries?

Tags: visas, india, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to India due to a visa technicality. I was advised by organisation I was travelling with to get tourist visa when I actually needed miscellaneous visa. Will this affect future travel to other countries if I have been refused once by a country, or if I want to re-enter India?

Comment: Not really. Every application is decided on its own merit. I would think that refusals by big western nations like UK, US would matter more, if they even do.

Answer (score 4):

In many visa applications, you will be asked "have you ever been denied a visa elsewhere" or "have you ever been denied entry elsewhere" or something like that.

- Having a travel history is usually a good point, since it shows that you have been a visitor and not an illegal immigrant in the past. Being denied a visa is the opposite of having a travel history.
- A denied visa is **much less serious** than a refused entry or deportation.
- Countries will weigh who denied the visa. If a sports journalist is denied entry by Russia, that might just mean he did his job reporting on doping.

**What you should take from this is the importance of reading and understanding visa application documents which are submitted with your signature. Visa officials worldwide expect that *you* take responsibility for *your* application. Blaming an advisor or agent is a really bad idea.**